# Failed to bounce to type with push Id Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "**-Jzp5XCUx78BX5D7BvkU**"

[image]

My POJO class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

public class ChatData {
    String messageId;
    String userName;
    String currentDate;
    String chatType;
    String messageType;
    String currentLocation;


    public ChatData() {

    }

    public ChatData(String messageId, String userName, String currentDate, String chatType, String messageType, String currentLocation) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
        this.chatType = chatType;
        this.messageType = messageType;
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getCurrentDate() {
        return currentDate;
    }

    public String getChatType() {
        return chatType;
    }

    public String getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    public String getCurrentLocation() {
        return currentLocation;
    }


}
```

Message Receiving side

```
public static final String CHAT_TYPE_FRIEND = "friend";
```

and currentChannel=6ca5c08c-9dd2-4f8f-8475-34a427c2354f

```
  // User node listener were all the user private messages arriving
    private void listenToUserNode() {

        try {
            Firebase mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIRE_BASE_URL).child(Constants.CHAT_TYPE_FRIEND + File.separator + currentChannel);
            mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    ChatData newMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
                    handleReceivedMessage(currentChannel,newMessage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Am facing an error while receiving a data from firebase onChild changed as my pojo is matching with the data but it throws error because there is no field for push id

Comment: Please add the code that creates a `Firebase` reference and that calls `getValue()` to your question. Without those I can only take an educated guess at what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that this answer is based based on the incomplete code you posted. It would be really helpful if you add the code that sets up the `Firebase` reference and calls `getValue()` to your question.*

It looks like you're trying to read a list of chat messages into a`ChatData` object:

```
Firebase messagesRef = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com/messages");
messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ChatData data = snapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
}
```

That won't work.

You have two options:

**Read each message in a loop**

In this snippet we'll use `snapshot.getChildren()` to iterate over the individual messages.

```
messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            ChatData data = child.getValue(ChatData.class);
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
}
```

**Read all messages into a map**

Alternatively we can read all messages into a map:

```
messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,ChatData>> chatsType = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,ChatData>>() {};
        Map<String,ChatData> chats = child.getValue(Map<String,ChatData>);
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the push IDs for the messages, you can `chats.values()`. But in that case you might want to consider why you're storing the messages with push IDs in the first place, instead of using your own `messageId` value.

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen, Its my mistake i have used a wrong Firebase reference to get the data